# writing .dat file into .txt file after encoding using ssis

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, flat-file, script-component

I have .dat FIle. I need to do some encoding on this file and need o save into a .txt file I am using script component in SSIS.

I have used SSIS Script component to impement this .

```
//have declared 2 read write variable FIleLoc and FileWrite
string fileIn = Variables.FileLoc;
string fileOut = Variables.FileWrite;
var x = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileIn);
byte[] encodedBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x);
byte[] unicodeBytes=
Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8,Encoding.Unicode,encodedBytes);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileOut, unicodeBytes);
Output0Buffer.Col = Variables.FileWrite;
```

When i try to debug the code its showing package executed successfully and the .txt file is not generated.

Comment: When i try  to debug the code its showing package executed successfully and the .txt file is not generated

Comment: Why not reading .data files using Flat File Connection manager without converting to txt

Answer (score 1):

You can read `.dat` file using a Flat File Connection Manager and select the UTF-8 encoding from the Code page drop down list as mentioned in the picture below. Then instead of writing a script to convert `.dat` file to `.txt` you can simply use a Data Flow Task that contains a Flat File Source (.dat) and a Flat File Destination (.txt) *(each one must have a seperate connection manager)*.

[image]

If you need to use a Script Task then I would suggest to read the file path from the Flat File connection manager similar to:

```
public void Main()
  {
      ConnectionManager conn = Dts.Connections["file.dat"];
      var path = conn.ConnectionString;
      //your encoding code 
      // if you want to access package variables use Dts.Variables["User::NeededVar"].Value;
      Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.The .dat file which i am having doesn't have any column headers.How will i load this into a destination text file using data flow task.Sorry to ask this i am new to SSIS

Comment: When you create a new Flat File Connection Manager for source you will have to uncheck "Column Names in the first data row" -> this will insert into destination with no headers. Otherwise, if you need to insert into a file with headers, check that checkbox and under Advanced section add column headers.

Comment: @user3035090 in the flat file connection manager go to advanced tab and add columns names manually.